# include a template inside another but with extend

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Here is what i want

**tmpl1.jinja**

```
{% for x in List %}
    {% set User = List[x] %}
    {% include 'tmpl2.jinja' %}
{% endfor %}
```

**tmpl2.jinja**

```
{% extends "tmpl3.jinja" %}    
{% block link %}
   <a>share</a>
{% endblock link %}
```

**tmpl3.jinja**

```
User.name
{% block link %}
{% endblock link %}
```

Basically i have a user block that exists across site with only the action(one or more link but with quiet a few html like image etc) changing. What can i do.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the template part everything looks absolutely ok and there should not be problem if what you do is what you showed.

Is Your list is dict() or actually list()?

Because your problem is here:

```
{% for x in List %}
    {% set User = List[x] %}
```

This syntax will work only if List is dictionary.

In case of list you should write:

```
{% for x in List %}
    {% set User = x %}
```